# How to show if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)=a$, ($a$ is a constant), then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^nf(x)dx=a$?

Tags: limits

I have no idea how to proof if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)=a$, ($a$ is a constant), then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^nf(x)dx=a$? Does anyone can tell me?

Comment: Is $n\in\mathbb N$? If yes, then this is not true. For instance, define $f(n):=1$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb R\backslash\mathbb N$. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=1$, but $\int_0^nf(x)dx=0$.

Comment: Separate in 2 integrals where $n\ge n_0\implies |f(n)-a|<\epsilon$. Also $a=\frac 1n\int_0^n a\,dx$.

Comment: I would say just use L'hopitals rule.

Comment: Just about the same as Cesaro mean = sequence limit when exists.

Comment: Thank you, every one. Thanks to your answers, I have become clear now. All bests.

Answer (score 2):

We must assume $f$ is integrable on $[0,n]$ for all $n$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, take $N$ so $|f(x)-a| < \epsilon/2$ for $x > N$.
Let $c = \int_0^N f(x)\; dx$.  Then for $n > N$, 
$$\eqalign{ \left| \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n f(x)\; dx - a \right| &=
\left| \frac{c}{n} - \frac{N}{n} a + \int_N^n \frac{f(x) - a}{n}\; dx \right|\cr
&\le \left|\frac{c-Na}{n} \right| + \frac{\epsilon}{2} }$$
and if $n$ is sufficiently large, this is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your specific interpretation. I became clear now. All bests,